# switch_to_blog() not functioning while querying post_types, Why?

Tags: multisite, network-admin

I have following code

```
<?php

$sites = get_sites();
foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
    switch_to_blog( $site->blog_id );
    echo bloginfo('name');              
    $args = array(
         'public'   => true,
         '_builtin' => false
    );
    $post_types = get_post_types( $args, '', 'and');
    foreach($post_types as $post_type){
    ?>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
<div class="card card-default text-center wow slideInUp" data-wow-duration="2s" >
<h4 class="card-text"><?php echo $post_type->label; ?></h4>
<p class="card-text"><i class="fa fa-5x fa-<?php echo $post_type->menu_icon; ?>"></i></p>
<p class="card-text">
  <a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-small" href="#">Read more<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i></a>
</p>
</div>
</div>

<?php 
    }
    restore_current_blog();
}    
?>
```

I want to grab all custom post created on sites in a network.
When I checked the blog_id it changes with new blog.
When I echoed bloginfo('name'), it also prints the name of different sites,
But when I query for custom post, it shows custom post only from current site.

Comment: Are the post types defined in the various sites in your network?

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be a couple things at work here:

1. The [`switch_to_blog()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_blog/) call does not switch plugins ([see ticket #14941](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14941)), so if your custom post types are defined in a plugin (as they most likely are and should be), then they won't be loaded in a `switch_to_blog()` scenario. (This is highly unlikely to changed, judging by the commentary on the ticket.)
2. Also, the [`get_post_types()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_types) uses a global variable; it doesn't grab the CPTs registered in the site you switch to, but the list from the site you started from. Global variables don't seem to be updated on `switch_to_blog()`, presumably for reasons similar to the reasons plugins aren't unloaded/loaded on `switch_to_blog()`.

I don't know that there's going to be an easy way to do what you're trying to do, I'm afraid.

### A possible work-around

[`register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) fires an action—[`registered_post_type`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/registered_post_type/)—as it finishes up. You should be able to use this to build a list of custom post types on a given site.

Something like this (very simple, untested code):

```
<?php

add_action( 'registered_post_type', 'wpse_290292_post_types', 10, 2 );
function wpse_290292_post_types( $post_type_name, $post_type_object ) {
    $post_types = get_option( 'my_prefix_post_types', array() );
    if ( 
        ! isset( $post_types[ $post_type_name ] ) 
        || $post_type_object !== $post_types[ $post_type_name ] 
    ) {
        // Adds the $post_type_object to the array if it's a) not already there or b) changed since it was added.
        $post_types[ $post_type_name ] = $post_type_object;
        update_option( 'my_prefix_post_types', $post_types );
    }
}
?>
```

This will add any registered post types to the `*_options` table. You'll probably want to add in some checks to prevent adding the `_builtin` post types, etc.

Once this is set up—probably as a network-enabled plugin—you should be able to get a given site's CPTs using the `my_prefix_post_types` option (feel free to rename that as needed).